# Concatenar query [MSSQL]

Tags: sql-server

Estou com uma dúvida em como eu poderia concatenar a coluna email, conforme query abaixo:

```
select * from orcam INNER JOIN ccusto as a ON orcam.Ccusto = a.Ccusto INNER JOIN grupo_email b on a.Ccusto 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = b.cc INNER JOIN grupo_resp c ON b.resp = c.id  where orcam.Ccusto=0151 and anomes=201709
```

Que me traz as informações:

```
Ccusto | Grupo | Anomes | Ccusto | cc | resp | id | email
0151     0452    201709   0151    0151  1      1    email01@mail.com
0151     0452    201709   0151    0151  1      2    email02@mail.com
```

Estou associando a coluna `cc` de acordo com a coluna Ccusto. Dessa maneira, ele me traz todos os responsáveis pelo `CCusto` cadastrado.

O problema, é que ele está repetindo para o mesmo grupo para cada email. O que eu estou tentando fazer, é a saída abaixo

```
Ccusto | Grupo | Anomes | Ccusto |  cc  | email
0151     0452    201709   0151    0151   email01@mail.com;email02@mail.com
```

Reparem que ele não repetiu o `Grupo` e concatenou o email02 após o primeiro e-mail. 
A ideia aqui é concatenar todos e-mails responsável pelo `Ccusto` 0151 para cada grupo na mesma linha.

Obrigado pessoal!

Comment: veja se ajuda: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem diversas formas, algumas mais fáceis dependendo da sua versão do Sql Server.

Essas respostas podem te ajudar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Exemplo Sql 2017

```
SELECT Ccusto , STRING_AGG(email, ', ') AS email
from orcam 
INNER JOIN ccusto as a ON orcam.Ccusto = a.Ccusto 
INNER JOIN grupo_email b on a.Ccusto COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = b.cc 
INNER JOIN grupo_resp c ON b.resp = c.id  
where orcam.Ccusto=0151 and anomes=201709
GROUP BY Ccusto ;
```

Exemplo Sql 2005

```
    SELECT Ccusto ,
(
            Select email + ',' AS [text()]
            From grupo_resp 
            Where id = b.resp 
            For XML PATH ('')    
) AS email
    from orcam 
    INNER JOIN ccusto as a ON orcam.Ccusto = a.Ccusto 
    INNER JOIN grupo_email b on a.Ccusto COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = b.cc 
    INNER JOIN grupo_resp c ON b.resp = c.id  
    where orcam.Ccusto=0151 and anomes=201709
    GROUP BY Ccusto ;
```

OBS: Como não tinha exemplo da estrutura da tabela, talvez algum campo esteja errado.

Comment: Engraçado que ele pede para colocar a coluna resp no group by: Column 'grupo_email.resp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Depois que eu coloco, a query funciona, mas ainda traz um embaixo do outro.

Comment: Eu criei um exemplo, para você usar como base, nas acredito que de erro devido a estrutura das tabelas estar diferente.
Você tem que colocar no group by todas as colunas que são consultadas, menos a do email.